# LUN larger than allowed by the host adapter

Tags: linux, raid, storage

We have `HP DL-360-g9` server which has `HP240` Raid controller and currently we have total 4 disk installed 2 (Mirror) for OS and 2 (1TB) individual disk in LVM group. now we running out of storage and decided to add more disk so we added 2x1TB disk in server but they are now showing up in linux CentOS7 `fdisk -l`. we did following

`echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/host0/scan`

In /var/log/messages seeing

```
[16507042.745884] scsi 0:0:0:0: lun4194304 has a LUN larger than allowed by the host adapter
[16507042.745892] scsi 0:0:0:0: lun4194560 has a LUN larger than allowed by the host adapter
[16507042.745895] scsi 0:0:0:0: lun4194816 has a LUN larger than allowed by the host adapter
```

here is the scsi

```
# cat /proc/scsi/scsi
Attached devices:
Host: scsi0 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 00
  Vendor: HP       Model: H240ar           Rev: 4.02
  Type:   RAID                             ANSI  SCSI revision: 05
Host: scsi0 Channel: 01 Id: 00 Lun: 00
  Vendor: HP       Model: LOGICAL VOLUME   Rev: 4.02
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI  SCSI revision: 05
Host: scsi0 Channel: 01 Id: 00 Lun: 01
  Vendor: HP       Model: LOGICAL VOLUME   Rev: 4.02
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI  SCSI revision: 05
Host: scsi0 Channel: 01 Id: 00 Lun: 02
  Vendor: HP       Model: LOGICAL VOLUME   Rev: 4.02
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI  SCSI revision: 05
Host: scsi0 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 4194240
  Vendor: HP       Model: H240ar           Rev: 4.02
  Type:   RAID                             ANSI  SCSI revision: 05
Host: scsi0 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 4194496
  Vendor: HP       Model: H240ar           Rev: 4.02
  Type:   RAID                             ANSI  SCSI revision: 05
Host: scsi0 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 4194752
  Vendor: HP       Model: H240ar           Rev: 4.02
  Type:   RAID                             ANSI  SCSI revision: 05
```

in /var/log/messages its showing disk has been detected

```
hpsa 0000:03:00.0: scsi 0:0:5:0: masked Direct-Access     ATA      Samsung SSD 850  PHYS DRV SSDSmartPathCap- En- Exp=0
hpsa 0000:03:00.0: scsi 0:0:6:0: masked Direct-Access     ATA      Samsung SSD 850  PHYS DRV SSDSmartPathCap- En- Exp=0
```

why my disk presenting very big `LUN` number should i set `max_lun=xxxxxx` in modprobe.conf to increase its number?

or should i tell RAID controller to handle disk instead of OS?

Comment: any suggestion?